# how to show CustomAlertDialog in an Adapter class?

Tags: java, android

please tell me how can I show my CustomAlertDialog from Adapter Class ? obviously `Application.getContext() , dialogObject` won't work and I should pass an Activity reference but I don't know how.

Adapter Class =>

```
public class mAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<E04Adapter.VH> {


List<mObject> object ;
dbConnector dbConnector;


public E04Adapter (List<mObject> object , dbConnector dbConnector) {
    this.object      = object      ;
    this.dbConnector = dbConnector ;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(Application.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_e04_row , parent , false) ;

    return new VH(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return object.size();
}

public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

 
    ImageButton    seenBtn     , deleteBtn    ;


    public VH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);



        firstLetter  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLetter) ;
        noteNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteNameText);

        seenBtn      = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seenBtn)     ;
        deleteBtn    = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn)   ;

        noteRowCard  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteRowCard) ;

        seenBtn    .setOnClickListener(this);
        noteRowCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteBtn  .setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        DialogObject dialogObject = new DialogObject() ;

        CustomDialogView customDialogView = new CustomDialogView(Application.getContext() , dialogObject) ;



        if (view == deleteBtn) {

    customDialogView.show();
        }
```

DialogClass =>

```
public class CustomDialogView extends AlertDialog implements View.OnClickListener {

DialogObject object ;

FloatingActionButton noFab , okFab ;

public CustomDialogView(Context context , DialogObject object) {
    super(context);
    this.object = object ;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);

    noFab = findViewById(R.id.noFab) ;
    okFab = findViewById(R.id.okFab) ;

    okFab.setOnClickListener(this);
    noFab.setOnClickListener(this);




}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == okFab) {
        object.getListener().onPositive();
    }

    else if (view == noFab) {
        object.getListener().onNegative();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Replace `Application.getContext()` with `view.getContext()`

Comment: @AlphaOne I already tested itemView.getContext(); isn’t it the same ?

Comment: Why don't you pass activity context in your adapter class?

Comment: Not the same. `itemView` is the parent view holding all other views and `view` is the particular view that's clicked by the user.  But it will not make much difference. is it working with itemView.getContext() ?

Comment: Instead of Creating a Dialog in the Adapter class, create an Interface with a function, implement it in the activity and pass it to the adapter, in adapter, call that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass listener from activity or fragment to adapter and show custom dialog inside listener. like this:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onClickItem(int position);
}


class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickItem(int position) {
        // show custom alert dialog.
    }

    //...
}

class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public MyAdapter(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //...
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView, onItemClickListener);
    }
    //...
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                onItemClickListener.onClickItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
    //..
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked out, but I faced another problem ; I'm using this AlertDialog in order to delete a note from database but when I delete note and after that I add a new note my AlertDialog appears again notwithstanding I have not clicked the delete button.